# Define the column control of a database-driven DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use a `DataGridView` to view and edit data in my PostgreSQL database, which works fine. I want to make it a little more user-friendly by choosing the right `Control` to input data. Specifically, I want to create a `ComboBox` in a column to let the user search and select a value fast.

To do so, I think I need the `EditingControlShowing` event to fill the combobox. However, the column I get is of type `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, so the corresponding `e.Control` is a `TextBox` instead of a `ComboBox`.

I never initialise those columns, because they come from views in the database. How can I cast/initialise the column to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` ?

This is how I populate my `DataGridView`:

```
dgView.DataSource = getView();
```

`getView()` returns a `DataTable` as can be gotten from `NpgsqlDataAdaper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use something other than a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` you need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and actually define the columns yourself. When defining them, choose a `DataGridViewComboBox` column for the appropriate fields.

This can be done in code, or in the designer, and based off your question I think you should be able to simply do it through the designer.

Comment: I can't do it in the designer, as almost all functionality and views are in the DB. I want to be able to just edit the DB and have these changes reflected in the application.

Comment: You should do this then http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/abb7be97-0a44-4e18-98bf-687a723645a9/combo-box-inside-datagridview-using-datatable

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in 2 steps. 
1. First of all ( as mentioned by Michael) you should set AutoGenerateColumns to false and then create the required columns using the datagrid view columns option (in properties)
2. Then you should loop through your records and assign appropriate values to appropriate columns.

In case you have hundreds of records that you are showing in grid view, than you should consider using server side paging.